# how to compare date from access database with date in texbox in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

my sql statement is returning null when when I compare date from access database and date entered in textbox in vb. seems to me that the two dates are of different format so null is returned from the select statement but how do I go about this. help please. my select is below:

```
("SELECT farmer_num as [FARMER'S NUMBER], " & _
                                         "farmer_name as [FARMER'S NAME], farmer_village     as [VILLAGE], farmer_phone as [PHONE NUMBER], reg_date as [REGISTRATION DATE], " & _
                                         "farmer_centre as [CENTRE] FROM farmer where reg_date =" & TextBox.Text.ToString, cnn)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point, you shouldn't be contencating in trusted user input into your SQL.  It makes your code very vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection), the most heavily exploited and easily prevented vulnerability out there.

You should be using [parameterized queries](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml) instead.

That alone may solve your issue if you're lucky. If you're using parameterized queries, then the data type conversion happens almost "magically".  You don't need to worry about it.

Here's a link to an article specifically dealing with Access databases and .NET to help you along:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access

Comment: Thank you very much. I just read the link and just added the `##` and all is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Well given regdate is of type date.

And somewhere you have the date displayed in textbox as a date somewhere in your code, then use a parameterised query, and the date, not the formatted string version of it as the parameter value.

Aside from @David's mention of SQl injection issues, always remember '8/6/2012' is a string not a date.

Comment: Thank you. Am using parametized query and staff is fantastic

Answer (score 0):

use like this..

```
("SELECT farmer_num as [FARMER'S NUMBER], " & _ "farmer_name as [FARMER'S NAME], farmer_village as [VILLAGE], farmer_phone as [PHONE NUMBER], reg_date as [REGISTRATION DATE], " & _ "farmer_centre as [CENTRE] FROM farmer where convert(datetime, '" & TextBox.Text.ToString &"', 101)";
```

You may have to change second parameter convert funciton if TextBox format different than mm/dd/yyyy.

string concat is not the proper solution for using parametered sql. try to use SqlCommand and SqlParameter.

Comment: I've just added `##` around `TextBox.Text.ToString` and it's working. Let me try your idea also. Thank you for the reply